# Guice auto bind implementation classes to interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, guice

I am attempting to reproduce Spring Component scan within Guice.

I want to use interfaces and have implementations that are annotated with `@Singleton` to be auto bound to their respective interfaces, if the implementation implements a single interface.

```java
import java.util.Set;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import org.reflections.Reflections;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class SingletonAutoBindModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String rootPackageName;

    public SingletonAutoBindModule(final String rootPackageName) {

        this.rootPackageName = rootPackageName;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        final Reflections reflectionsOfPackage = new Reflections(rootPackageName);

        final Set<Class<?>> typesWithSingletonAnnotation =
            reflectionsOfPackage.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Singleton.class);

        for (Class<?> aClass : typesWithSingletonAnnotation) {
            final Class<?>[] interfaces = aClass.getInterfaces();

            if (interfaces.length == 1) {
                final Class<?> anInterface = interfaces[0];

                bind(anInterface).to(aClass);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting compilation error around line:

```
 bind(anInterface).to(aClass);
```

Error:

```
java: no suitable method found for to(java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?>)
    method com.google.inject.binder.LinkedBindingBuilder.to(java.lang.Class<? extends capture#2 of ?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends capture#2 of ?>)
    method com.google.inject.binder.LinkedBindingBuilder.to(com.google.inject.TypeLiteral<? extends capture#2 of ?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to com.google.inject.TypeLiteral<? extends capture#2 of ?>)
    method com.google.inject.binder.LinkedBindingBuilder.to(com.google.inject.Key<? extends capture#2 of ?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to com.google.inject.Key<? extends capture#2 of ?>)
```

Is there a way to make this type of auto bind work in Guice?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you probably `TypeLiteral#get(Class<?>)` provide some benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an auto binding, but very close.

Have a look at https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings. There you will find `@ImplementedBy` which can be used as:

```java
@ImplementedBy(UserRepositoryImpl.class)
public interface UserRepository {
  //...
}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
  //...
}
```

Now when you inject `UserRepository`, an instance of `UserRepositoryImpl` will be used without having to `bind(UserRepository.class).to(UserRepositoryImpl.class)`